# When giving user input I don't want to have to put quotations is this possible?

Tags: python, input

I'm trying to get user input on something but it's not very user friendly to have to put quotations each time you type an answer.

```
    loop = True
    while loop:

        user_input = input("say hello \n")
        if user_input == "hello":
        print("True")
```

I want to be able to just type hello and not have to add the quotations (ex. "hello").

Comment: you won't have to. run the program and it should work without the quote.

Comment: Upgrade to python 3. Alternatively, use `raw_input`.

Comment: Is this python 2.x? If so, then use `raw_input`

Comment: It is literally required by the language to have quotes to distinguish objects from string literals

Comment: so when I'm getting user input I have to type "hello" with quotes the but I want to be able to just type hello.

Comment: @CoryKramer I think they mean when typing in terminal

Comment: just to make my program more user friendly

Comment: Yea when typing in the terminal.

Comment: Why are people down voting this question? please let the asker know.

Comment: @VikashSingh Because we had to figure out that op is using `input` on python2, when the question is not tagged as such, and that they are `eval`ing input by default.

Comment: @Asori12 Use `user_input = raw_input("say hello \n")`

Comment: @VikashSingh The fact that people in the comments are interpreting the question 3 different ways would suggest that the question is quite obviously unclear.

Comment: @Rawing the user is clearly a newbie. Tell him/her in comments what's wrong with the question and how to improve it.

Comment: So put version of python in the question or tag?

Comment: that would definitely help. also could have been clearer about where you were talking about the quotes (i.e. in your code or in the input)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Python 3.6 interactive prompt:

```
>>> user_input = input("say hello \n")
say hello 
hello
>>> user_input
'hello'
```

you need to quote the string when you check equality, but shouldn't need to for the input. as others have said, in python 2.x, use `raw_input`. Python 2.7:

```
>>> user_input = raw_input("say hello \n")
say hello 
hello
>>> user_input
'hello'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a slight difference in between input and raw_input: [What's the difference between raw_input() and input() in python3.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x)

python 2.7:

```
loop = True
hello_input = "hello"
while loop:
    user_input = raw_input("say hello \n")
    if user_input == hello_input:
        print("True")
```

python 3:

```
loop = True
hello_input = "hello"
while loop:
    user_input = input("say hello \n")
    if user_input == hello_input:
        print("True")
```

When you run these programs you wont have to put input in terminal with quotes:

eg:

```
say hello
hello
True
```

Comment: If you think a question is a duplicate then you should flag it as such, as written, there is no way to know if this really is the issue.

Comment: @Sayse The question is not a duplicate because the Asker does not know that what he/she is looking for is a different approach for the same problem. ie: use `raw_input` instead of `input`.